# Anchor tags in asp.net 2.0 to pass variables to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm learning asp.net 2.0 for a project and so far after several tutorials and searching it's going pretty well. However what I am having problems with is I have a main page with a huge list of anchor tags and need a way to have the user click one and redirect to another page along with a variable or two so the new page an be dynamically created pulling database info based off those two variables. So far I can do this just fine for one item with a form, submit button and postback but with a huge list of anchor tags it doesn't really make a lot of sense.  I really don't know what I'm trying to do is called so I don't know what to search on the internet to learn how to do it. I'm hoping someone may have a suggestion to point me in the right direction.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Custoemr1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Custoemr2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Custoemr3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Custoemr4</a></li>
</ul>
```

above is the sample list and it doesn't have to be anchor tags I just need to be able to not have to write a new form for every customer , it's an odd project trying to combine a lot of database info as well as a lot of static pages.

Comment: Can you please give a small example with code ?

Comment: You probably want to append something to the query string, for example `<a href="#?customerId=1">Customer1</a>` and then pull that value.